# jQuery 'click' behaves like doubleclick

Tags: jquery, css

Goal: on a single click to animate a div, not only on initial loading of the page.

Problem: when I load the page, it behaves like I want it to but when I try to click the element again it won't work -- unless I click the element twice. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/V5LBk/10/

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('h1.slide1').live('click', function() {
        $("div#slidebox1").animate({
            top: -129
        }, 300);
        $("div#slidebox2").animate({
            top: 115
        }, 300);
        $("div#slidebox3").animate({
            top: 115
        }, 300);
        $(this).removeClass("slide1").addClass("selected");
    });
    $("h1.selected").live('click', function() {
        $("div#slidebox1").animate({
            top: 115
        }, 300);
        $(this).removeClass("selected").addClass("slide1");
    });
    $('h1.slide2').live('click', function() {
        $("div#slidebox2").animate({
            top: -129
        }, 300);
        $("div#slidebox1").animate({
            top: 115
        }, 300);
        $("div#slidebox3").animate({
            top: 115
        }, 300);
        $(this).removeClass("slide2").addClass("selected2");
    });
});​
```

**CSS**

```
#slidebox h1{ 
    font-size:12px; 
    height:30px; 
    color:#212121; 
    font-weight:bold; 
    z-index:11; 
    cursor:pointer; 
}
```

Comment: The code you posted is valid and shouldn't have the side effects you are describing. What else could be going on?

Comment: We need to see CSS and HTML, there is a possibility that one of the divs are sliding on top of the h1, making it impossible to click the h1.

Comment: That is pretty likely actually, considering the type of animation that is happening. http://jsfiddle.net/V5LBk/

Comment: I don't think other layers are hiding it because it is working on first load. I have a few of these h1.slides. I will go ahead and edit my question to add more info. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Umm. Try setting the focus on the div using `.blur()` onload. Does it help?

Comment: People need to start using Jsfiddle more often. Would be a lot easier for us to help.

Comment: @mario - Sorry, it is a massive project and it's very difficult to really separate this part. You are right though.

Comment: don't use .live(). Use .unbind().bind('click', //some function)

Comment: Here's your code. I don't quite understand what the goal is yet. http://jsfiddle.net/V5LBk/1/

Comment: @Pablo, jQuery's `.live` & `.bind` [should be replaced with `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: Ok, I updated http://jsfiddle.net/V5LBk/9/, thank you @Kevin B. Now, I click test 1 then test2. Now, try to click test 1 again and you will have to click it twice in order to make it animate. Sorry if the code is not super elegant. Trying to learn.

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/V5LBk/11/ is that what you wanted?

Comment: It's better to post the code _along with_ the jsFiddle.  Sometimes the fiddle links go dead which would render the question useless. Rolled it back and added the jsFiddle link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `.click()` instead of `.live('click'..` and things worked.

http://jsfiddle.net/eKYxC/

Comment: Isn't `.click()` a shorthand for `.on("click", handler)` ?